# Formatting table caption

Tags: formatting

So I have my table

```
\begin{table}
\center
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}\hline
table stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{Lots of words about table}
\end{table}
```

I want it so that the caption fits to the table, kind of the same as changing the indents in Word.  Is there a way to do this?

Additionally, I have something similar to:

```
\newpage
\subsection{NAme}
TABLE STUFF INCLUDED ABOVE
\subsubsection{Name}
```

And the table appears at the top of the page, not in between the title of the subsection and the sub subsection.  Can I change this?

Comment: On the first question, see [How to align table or figure caption where the table starts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10083) and [Table caption Width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7276). On the second question see [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275). I think your question is a duplicate of these.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all; what do you mean by "so that the caption fits to the table"? (I have no idea how things are working in M$ Word.) Also, please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).